# How to insert about 300 items to drop down list (without affecting performance)?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am getting about 300 items in a web service call. I need to add them into a drop down list. I have done this using the following underscore template:

```
<select>
<% _.each(data, function (item) { %>
<option><% print(item) %></option>
<% }); %>
</select>
```

But this code is affecting performance. Please let me know any method to do this without iterating the list.

*Note: Backbone.js and underscore.js are used in my project. I welcome solutions in javascript and jquery also*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its using underscore.js

Comment: if you are using jquery, you'd be better off using your loop to create a string, and once you've looped through them all, use jquery to insert the whole thing, inserting one large select will be better then inserting each option one at a time

Comment: Simply don't use a select box for 300 items, that's just silly..

Comment: hehe... but the client expect us to provide such a select box :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It REALLY depends on the availability in your application. For example, you can have a timer running with 1ms interval, inserting one element at a time. Thus it takes 300ms to build the select. That will ofc introduce a 300ms delay until the data is ready; but it will not interrupt the UI-thread.

The other method is to use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) instead. This works by appending all items to the `fragment` first, then append the fragment to the DOM-tree - causing only **ONE** dom-manipulation instead of **300**.

The third option is to generate the markup server-side.

The fourth option is only known by God, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Except ajax, setTimeout and setInterval, there is nothing that can asynchronously execute in JavaScript.

You need to consider doing this through a back-end solution, or simply try to find the cheapest execution of the synchronous code

Without being an expert on code efficiency, I believe a regular for-loop is one of the fastest ways to print an array of items.

```
<script>
   var location = '#options'
   for(var i = 0; 0 < data.length; i++){
      $(location).append(data[i]);
   }

</script>

<option id="options">

</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var option = "";
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  option += "<option>"+item+ "<option>";
});

$('select').append(option);
```